# How to render multiple meshes using DirectX 11

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am working on a graphics engine in c++ and DirectX 11. While importing scenes (using Assimp) I have to render multiple meshes with separate shaders. I do this by the following method
I have an std::vector to store shaders and another one for meshes. After I open the file I add all the meshes to that vector. Next, I iterate over the elements of the vector using a for loop and draw each of them separately. After having drawn all the meshes I swap the buffer. This works perfectly fine except for the framerate/performance which is terrible.

I am not aware how this can be done more efficiently or how this kind of thing is supposed to be done.

```cpp
void CRenderer::RenderFrame(void(*r)(void), void(*gui)(void),std::vector<CMesh>& meshStr, std::vector<CShader>& shaderStr)
{
    const float BackColor[4] = { 0.03f, 0.03f, 0.03f, 1.f };
    DeviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(DepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
    DeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, BackColor);

    for (int i = 0; i < shaderStr.size(); i++)
    {
        UseShader(&shaderStr[i], sizeof(Vertex), 0);

            r();

        DeviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

        DeviceContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &CurrentShader->GetConstantBuffer());
        DeviceContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &CurrentShader->GetConstantBuffer());

        DeviceContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(1, 1, &CurrentShader->GetLightConstantBuffer());
        DeviceContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(1, 1, &CurrentShader->GetLightConstantBuffer());

        DeviceContext->DrawIndexed(meshStr[i].GetIndicesCount(), 0, 0);
    }

    gui();

    SwapChain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Is it slow due to CPU or GPU? How many meshes do you have? How many vertices/triangles? How do you set vertex/index buffers? What `r` function does?

Comment: I am not sure if the CPU is causing the slowdown or the GPU but as far as i can tell it should be the  CPU.it depends, i mean it lags with any file that i try to load, however for this specific test it's 7 meshes, but nothing that my gpu should not be able to handle with ease. the Vertex and index buffers are bound in the UseShader(). (sorry; forgot to provide the source code for that) function. r() is just a function pointer for updating the constant buffers for Matrices and lighting vectors, colors etc.

Comment: Hm, strange. It doesn't look bad, should work fine. So, it must be profiled to figure out the actual reason. I can try to help you with that, but you'll have to share your project or, at least, runnable binaries with debug symbols.

Comment: Or you can try to do it yourself. At first, I'd check GPU by taking frame capture in Intel GPA. It'll show you how fast the GPU part. If frame time is smaller than frame time you see in your program than you're CPU limited and you should profile CPU part (vTune if you have it, VerySleepy or manual instrumentation)

Comment: First of all Thanks for the quick response, i used Intel GPA, it seems that my CPU is fine, the GPU is what is causing the bottleneck. its a 1050 ti 4 GB and i think it should be able to handle a much more complicated scene with ease. The frame time is sitting at about 4000, leaping up-to and even over 10000 every now and then. The GPU Duration remains consistently lesser. After realizing that the GPU is causing the bottleneck i am even more confused...

Comment: Now I'm confused :-) What is your frame time in GPA and what time you have in your program?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The GPU frame time is around 4000 and GPU Duration is around 2500. I can share the app if you would test it on your computer...

Comment: Yeah, I could take a look

Comment: How should i share the project with you?

Comment: If you don't mind share sources you can use GitHub. Or you can use Dropbox, google drive, etc :-)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qS6emCaEjynmagxUTRCZO13-tkks3F4r

Comment: Remember to copy the assimp32.dll to the debug folder. and also debug it in x86 mode. If the open dialog doesn't work try changing the default directory in EngineDX\last_dir.txt because the file OpenFile dialog is not perfected yet. rest it should work fine...

Comment: @MichaelNastenko did you check it out?

Comment: Sorry, I can do this only on weekends

Comment: Can you share a test model - I tried to load some, but it crashes

Comment: Here's what i was using https://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/418280

Comment: Ok, first of all - `GetPerspectiveProjectionMatrix` and `GetViewMatrix` return reference to local variable. It causes the mesh to be rendered incorrectly. And about performance - rendering performance is fine - I have 0.5-1ms per frame on my machine. But you tick you renderer in `WindowProc`! This is very bad - you force renderer to draw something every time you window get any message. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: what is the right way then?

Comment: if i do it outside the message loop it would stop the WinMessages

Comment: Not at all. Usually, the loop looks like this - 1. Process all windows messages; 2. Render viewport; 3. (Optional) Wait till certain frame time is reached (to limit max FPS - no need to render more than 60-100 FPS for most programs). Like this: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59857/game-loop-on-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you shouldn't render in `WindowProc`.
The proper way would be processing all messages at the beginning of every tick and rendering frame then.
Like this:

```
void CWindow::BeginTick(void(*ETick)())
{
    GetCursorPos(&LastMousePosition);
    LastTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    while (true)
    {
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        GetCursorPos(&CurrentMousePosition);
        CurrentTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        UpdateDeltaTime();

        ETick();
    }
}
```

With this frame loop, I have about 0.8ms per frame

Second, you have a lot of issues:

1. `GetPerspectiveProjectionMatrix` and `GetViewMatrix` return reference to local variable. It causes the mesh to be rendered incorrectly.
2. Bug in `OpenCdlg` - you allocate `len - 4` characters, but you read `len`.

   ```
   txt_path = new char[len - 4];
   f.seekg(0);
   f.read(txt_path, sizeof(char) * len);
   ```

   Should be

   ```
   txt_path = new char[len + 1]; // allocate len + 1 for terminator
   f.seekg(0);
   f.read(txt_path, sizeof(char) * len);
   txt_path[len] = 0; // add zero terminator
   ```